# How to organize a system of parent and child windows that hide their parent. QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Let’s say I have a main window.

Then when I click a button I want a child window to open up and that main windows to hide.
Then when I close that child window i want the main windows to reappear.

Right now I’m opening up that child window by doing:

```
s=new SignUpWindow(NULL,temp);
s->show();
```

where s is a private pointer of my main window.

When I try to do:

```
s=new SignUpWindow(this,temp);
s->show();
```

The s window doesn’t show up.

Here is the signature of it’s constructor in it's header:

```
SignUpWindow (QWidget* parent=NULL, Netflix *n=NULL);
```

Can someone also explain why we set parent to NULL in the header? 
I sometimes get issues when I try to play around with it's parameters and get errors like:

> candidate expects 1 argument,  2 provided qt

Thanks for all you're help
-A tired college student just learning qt

*UPDATE*
the following is essentially the header for my main window:

```
class LoginWindow : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        LoginWindow (QWidget* parent=NULL, Netflix *n=NULL);

    public slots:
        void loggedIn();
        void newUser();
        void quitPushed();


    private:
        QPushButton *quitButton, *loginButton, *newUserButton;
        QLineEdit *login;//this is the text area that takes in the loginID    
};

#endif
```

then there is a function that is initiated by a button click that opens up a new windows:

```
void LoginWindow::newUser()
{
        s=new SignUpWindow(NULL,temp);
        s->show();
        //this->hide();
}
```

How would I connect **s** to LogInWindow?

**UPDATE 2**
SignUpWIndow.h:

```
class SignUpWindow : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SignUpWindow (QWidget* parent=NULL, Netflix *n=NULL);


    public slots:

    private:
 };
```

SignUpWindow.cpp:

```
SignUpWindow::SignUpWindow (QWidget* parent, Netflix *n) : QWidget (parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    //then i add things like buttons and group boxes and etc but no dialogs...
}
```

I never made a dialog for my SignUpWindow. I just added layouts and buttons etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `signUpWindow` inside `loginWindow` set `this` as a parent. In this case you will be able to call `parentWidget()` inside the `signUpWindow` and call `hide()`, when you close your `signUpWindow`, call `parentWidget()` again and call `show().` It will work only when parent of `signUpWindow` is `loginWindow`.

In your code parent is `NULL` but it works when parent is `this`.

But your `signUpWindow` should be a `dialog` or:

If `signUpWindow` is a `widget` then when you set parent, your `signUpWindow` appears on parent, but `QDialog` appears in separate window. If you use `QDialog` subclass you set this as parent and use my solution, but if you use `QWidget` subclass you set `NULL` as parent and you can't use `parent-child` relationship, so you should use signals and slots (catch signal from `signUpWindow` and show or hide your `loginWindow`). Make your choice, but pay attention that `QDialog` is more suitable for this task.

Also I suggest you to use `closeEvent` to be sure that you can catch closing when user clicks on `close button`.

I wrote this dialog and I tested it, works fine:

Header:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QCloseEvent>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~Dialog();

protected:

    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *);

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;


};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Cpp:

```
//constructor
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    parentWidget()->hide();
}

//closeEvent
void Dialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
{
    parentWidget()->show();
}
```

Usage (inside mainWindow):

```
Dialog *mDialog = new Dialog(this);
mDialog->show();
```

As you can see I set parent but dialog appears as a separate windows and you still can use `parent-child` relationship.

Works as you want and it is very easy, just add a few lines of code.

Comment: what do you mean create dialog inside mainWindow?

Comment: @user3247278 signUpWindow is dialog and you create it inside mainWindow

Comment: i've added some extra code for context. But i don't know what you mean by signUpWindow is dialog

Comment: @user3247278 Post signUpWindow code, I want to know why you can't set this as a parent

Comment: @user3247278 you code was helpful, I understood why this as parent does not work, check my updated answer please.

Comment: so are you saying because signup window is a qwidget i can't pass "this" as the parent? Or are you saying that is what I should do? Because I tried passing this instead of null and the new SignUpWindow would not open.

Comment: @user3247278 It did not open because it is Qwidget subclass not a QDialog. Qwidget appears in separate window only when it has no parent. If it has parent, it appears on parent. QDialog appears in separate window every time, with parent or not

Comment: I see. I really appreciate your help! How difficult would to change it from a qwidget to a qdialog given that I have lots of buttons an what not on it...

Comment: @user3247278 I see that it can be problem for you. Next 1 hour I will be offline, but after this I will try to make the simplest solution for you. If your code is not top secret then you can give me full signUpWindow, then I can get more accurate code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64533/discussion-between-user3247278-and-chernobyl).

Comment: @user3247278 I added example, check it please. I don't need your code, don't post it, other people should not see this code.

Comment: Thank you so much Cherynobyl!! I finally got it. Now I just need to make it's layouts and other things. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: would I be able to add qpush buttons to the qdialog?

Comment: @user3247278 It is very good. Of course you can, do this with qt designer or add buttons to the layout, qdialog is very similar to widget.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone also explain why we set parent to NULL in the header?

You don't set the parent to NULL, you provide a default value for the parent if none is passed. This is done to avoid having an extra constructor for the cases you create an object without a parent, and it works the same way, you just omit passing a parent and instead the default NULL is used.

---

Do you have to use `QWidget`s? Keep in mind this module is no longer actively developed in Qt and is there pretty much only for backward compatibility. Qt GUI now focuses on QtQuick, which is much faster and easier to work with.

QtQuick even provides a ready to use [`StackView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) component which does exactly that, puts a new component (QML's widget) on top of the parent which is hidden, until you pop the new window, at which point the parent window appears again, it even has some funky animation when showing and hiding components.

Also QtQuick provides [QtQuick Controls](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-overview.html) which are implemented to look native to the platform, so they will look the same way the old `QWidget` based components look.

Just to give you an idea of how simple using QtQuick is, here is a short example. It will show a dialog of random color with text that says which level it is and 2 buttons - one to create another dialog on top of it, the other to close that dialog or the application if it is the first dialog:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    function randomColor() { return Qt.lighter(Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(), Math.random(), 1))}

    StackView {
        id: stack
    }

    Component {
        id: dialog

        Rectangle {
            color: randomColor()
            Column {
                Text {
                    text: "We are on level " + stack.depth
                }
                Row {
                    Button {
                        text: "Snow Another"
                        onClicked: stack.push(dialog)
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: "Close"
                        onClicked: {
                            if (stack.depth != 1) stack.pop()
                            else Qt.quit()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: stack.push(dialog)
}
```